# Godaddy .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, shared-hosting

EDIT - Further to the original post below. I tried installing on a different web server (Synology) and even without the example rules below it functioned. I could get to install, there were other errors (curl not installed) but the page loaded and I could begin the process of installing the site. This makes me think that maybe mod_rewite isn't functioning but I have other sites running with .htaccess re-writes working so I am even more confused.

---

I know this has been posted about many many many times but I am unable to find a solution and I have been googling for HOURS and tried many combinations of code to find a solution. I am trying to configure a site on Godaddy Ultimate Linux hosting. I have multiple domains setup on this hosting and I am using one of the domains to host this site.

Following the installation instructions from the sites Wiki it says the following:

> Apache configuration mod_rewrite MUST be enabled: a2enmod rewrite on
> Debian/Ubuntu, rewrite APACHE2_MODULES flag on Gentoo.

**Apache < 2.4
example :**

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/flightairmap/htdocs"
<Directory /var/www/flightairmap/htdocs>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Apache > 2.4
example :**

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/flightairmap/htdocs"
<Directory /var/www/flightairmap/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have apache 2.4.48 so I am using the bottom example and I am 99% sure that mod_rewrite is enabled.

I am hosting this site in the root of the domain, there are no other files in there and have copied the site files directly into a sub directory called "flightairmap".

I then created a .htaccess file and put the following.

```
RewriteEngine on

DocumentRoot "/var/www/flightairmap/htdocs"
<Directory /var/www/flightairmap/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I got an internal server error 500, which I partially expected as I felt the document root and directory options were wrong.

So given that the folder is in the root of the domain with no var/www etc I tried

```
RewriteEngine on

DocumentRoot "/flightairmap/htdocs"
<Directory /flightairmap/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Still no luck, same error.

Now I'm a bit confused by the htdocs part of the location as there is no htdocs folder in the files I have downloaded from github so not even really sure what this rule is trying to accomplish.

Without the rule going to /install/index.php results "This page isn't working, unable to handle this request" with the rule in place I get server error 500.

The site I am trying to get working is here - https://github.com/Ysurac/FlightAirMap/wiki/Installation

I do match all the requirements on the first page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) You can't specify `DocumentRoot` in an .htaccess file.  If you [check the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot), you'll see *Context: server config, virtual host* (ie not htaccess). The examples they've show are the config settings required for htacess to work, not actual htaccess files.  Presumably there is an htaccess file in their code. 2) "*... copied the site files directly into a sub directory called "flightairmap".* - your files need to go in `DocumentRoot`.  Not `flightairmap`, but `/var/www/flightairmap/htdocs`.

Comment: 3) 500 errors are just the bare-bones error shown to the world so as not to give away too much technical info about what is actually wrong.  The server logs will show you exactly what the problem is, you need to be checking those.

Comment: Thanks Don't Panic for your reply, very useful.

I copied the files into the root directory and got another 500 error. Looking at the logs I am getting the following

[Thu Sep 23 01:12:38.566597 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 3743154:tid 47187677697792] [client 64.120.109.209:38187] AH01276: Cannot serve directory: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: Which googling makes me think I need to add Options +Indexes to the .htaccess file however that didn't work either I then got an error telling me "Directory not allowed here which is what you said in your reply above.. I don't think I have access to configure the virtual host entry on Godaddy.. but I am assuming that is where I need to change the options

Comment: I've abandoned my Godaddy hosting for now and have got it running on a windows server with WAMP where I can control the VirtualHosts entries.

Thanks again Don't Panic

Comment: Glad you have it working.  GoDaddy is huge and has been around for decades, there is certainly a way to set up htaccess there if you want to pursue it.  Try their help docs etc.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I've been with them for the last 15 years, I've never experienced anything like this before it's a strange one for sure. Thanks again.